# Photo sphere image upload validation

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, photosphere

I'm trying to make my photo sphere gallery with MVC C#. Is there any way to test an image that is a real sphere image? A library or something? I'm currently having an upload button and I save the image's path in the Database. But I would like to validate the image that it is a real sphere image. I was searching for hours but no luck... 
Thank you!

Comment: I think only the human eyes are able to tell if an image is a panoramic shot

Comment: There are some websites that hosts spheric images and they actually return an error if the image is not spheric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I figured it out how to solve this. I found multiple solutions:

- Inspect the image's **XMP** data if it's available. The projection type **equirectangular** is enough for detection. There are some libraries that can be used to get EXIF, XMP,...metadata
- Inspect the picture size. Usually speric images have **2x1** ratio, so if you devide the image width with the image height you should get 2 or a number higher. I also add the limitation that image width should be greater then 1000px.